# How can I remove square bracket using regexp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

my_Query -

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('datavalue=Document{{value=[5]}}', 'datavalue=Document{{value=([^d}},'']+)'))[1] response;
```

current output is square bracket - `[5]`

I require without square bracket - `5`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a part of a string based on a regex, `substring()` is the better alternative:

```
substring('datavalue=Document{{value=[5]}}' from 'datavalue=Document{{value=\[([0-9]+)\]}}') response;
```